# Assign unique IDs to objects using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
static <T> Map<T, Integer> assignIds(Collection<T> objects);
```

I want to write a function that takes a collection of unique objects and assigns a different ID number to each. The ID numbers should be assigned sequentially.

I could easily do this with an explicit loop like:

```
Map<T, Integer> ids = new HashMap<>();
int id = 0;

for (T object: objects) {
    ids.put(object, id++);
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this with the new Java 8 [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
static <T> Map<T, Integer> assignIds(Collection<T> objects) {
    AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
    return objects.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o, o -> ai.getAndIncrement()));
}
```

The above solution could also make use of `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`.

Here's another that works sequentially:

```
static <T> Map<T, Integer> assignIds(Collection<T> objects) {
    Map<T, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    objects.stream().forEachOrdered(o -> result.put(o, result.size()));        
    return result;
}
```

Building upon ZouZou's answer...

```
static <T> Map<T, Integer> assignIds(Collection<T> objects) {
    OfInt ids = IntStream.range(0, objects.size()).iterator();
    return objects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o, o -> ids.next()));
}
```

The idiomatic way to do this in for instance Scala would be to use `zipWithIndex`. There's no such method in the Java 8 Streams API, not even a `zip` method which you could combine with an `IntStream`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a primitive iterator to generate the ids:

```
static <T> Map<T, Integer> assignIds(Collection<T> objects) {
    PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator = IntStream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1)
                .limit(objects.size())
                .iterator();
    return objects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> obj, id -> iterator.next()));
}
```

You might be interested to use the [protonpack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) library which defines some utility methods for Streams (such as `zipWithIndex`). So it could looks like this:

```
static <T> Map<T, Long> assignIds(Collection<T> objects) {
    return StreamUtils.zipWithIndex(objects.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Indexed::getValue, Indexed::getIndex));
}
```